# How can I use 'AS' in my count query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

How can I use **AS** in my count query?

Actually i want to result like `{ "count":"number" }` for json result. I dont know what should i call this thing?

```
public function firstHourTrades(){

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $data = DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')

        ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '>=', DB::raw('exchanges.start_time'))
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '<=', DB::raw("ADDTIME(exchanges.start_time, '1:00:00')"))
        ->count();

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use Eloquent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do a raw select and manually assign the alias:

```
$data = DB::table('finaltrade')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
    ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
    ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
    ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '>=', DB::raw('exchanges.start_time'))
    ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '<=', DB::raw("ADDTIME(exchanges.start_time, '1:00:00')"))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Excellent correction in my code. let me try it. I want to learn different method and use different logic. Thank you so much, Mr. Tim.